# Sorting multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a code that creates a multi-dimensional array of suffixes of a given string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   char seq[] = {"HELLO"};
   char suff[40][40];

   //Getting the suffixes
   for(int x = 0; seq[x] != '\0'; x++){
      for(int y = x; seq[y] != '\0'; y++){
         suff[x][y] = seq[y];
         printf("%c", suff[x][y]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The suffixes of the given string `HELLO` are:

`0  HELLO
1  ELLO
2  LLO
3  LO
4  O`

How can I sort the elements using bubble sort in ascending order like:

`1  ELLO
0  HELLO
3  LO
2  LLO
4  O`

and store its sorted indices into another array? `indices[] = {1,0,3,2,4}`

Comment: Do you have a code written for bubble sort of something simpler like integers?

Comment: You can not expect someone to write the code for you.

Comment: yeah but I can only sort 1d array and I'm having trouble sorting this 2d array. I'm running out of time so I decided to resort to this forum :)

Comment: If you have sorted 1D array, you should add that code here. We can guide you in the right direction for the 2D array in that case.

Comment: You might want to rethink your approach (and phrasing of the question). You are not trying to sort anything 2D you are trying to sort a list of "strings" (as far as that exists in C), without any special sorting needs within the strings. So you actually have a 1D sorting. You might change your representation/implementation to a single array of pointers to strings. Using quicksort then would only be a matter of getting the comparison of two strings right.

Comment: @Yunnosch: that's what I'm suspecting initially. I'm actually going to convert this code to assembly language that's why I want it to be as procedural as possible. Pardon me but I have a greater problem ahead in coding it in assembly and again I don't have much luxury of time reviewing about C.

@AjayBrahmakshatriya: when I compare `suff[0]` with `suff[1]`, `TGCAB` is less than `GCAB`. Why is that?

Comment: You are asking a question, tagging it C. If you do not want C, then do not tag it. If you want C then please do not consider your time spent on C more valuable than the time answerers here spend on trying to help you.

Comment: Indirect addressing, implemented in assembler, seems a feasible method of recreating a pointer-using C solution. Especially considering that the C-solution is what you expect to be given. Also, restricting the solution by forbidding pointers will most likely be a restriction on efficiency.

Comment: In case you really want to restrict everything to pointer-free solutions, then please consider stating that explicitly in your question. Giving a reason for it is recommended, even if I do not understand it.

Comment: Why does `LO` sort before `LLO`?  Even in (old) Spanish where `LL` was a separate letter from `L`, the alternative letter collated after `L` and before `M` (and therefore also before `O`).

Comment: @pgtr3s that is probably because you are comparing in the wrong way. I assume you are comparing as `suff[0] < suff[1]`. You need to use [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)

Comment: When using `indices`, it is not necessary to exchange actual strings. So, you can use a your bubble sort like 1DArray. (You will use comparison of strings as condition of exchange.)

Answer (score 2):

The `index` array means that you can sort the data without having to move any strings at all.  This code is closely related to the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152224) by [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin), but generates the output requested, apart from sorting `LLO` before `LO` (a problem I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151134/sorting-multidimensional-array-in-c#comment81252803_47151134)).  I've repackaged the code, creating a sorting function, a printing function that calls the sorting function, and a main function that calls the printing and sorting function for different strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void sort_substrings(size_t length, const char seq[length], size_t index[length])
{
    const char *suff[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; seq[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        suff[i] = &seq[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < length; j++)     /* bubblesort pointers */
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 1 - j; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(suff[index[i]], suff[index[i + 1]]) > 0)
            {
                int tmp = index[i];
                index[i] = index[i+1];
                index[i+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void test_sort_substrings(const char *str)
{
    size_t length = strlen(str);
    size_t index[length];

    sort_substrings(length, str, index);

    int width = (length > 9) ? 2 : 1;

    printf("\nString: [%s]\n", str);
    printf("Sorted data:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%*zu [%s]\n", width, index[i], &str[index[i]]);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Unsorted data:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%*zu [%s]\n", width, i, &str[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    test_sort_substrings("HELLO");
    test_sort_substrings("SALAMANDER");
    test_sort_substrings("ABLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
String: [HELLO]
Sorted data:
1 [ELLO]
0 [HELLO]
2 [LLO]
3 [LO]
4 [O]

Unsorted data:
0 [HELLO]
1 [ELLO]
2 [LLO]
3 [LO]
4 [O]


String: [SALAMANDER]
Sorted data:
 1 [ALAMANDER]
 3 [AMANDER]
 5 [ANDER]
 7 [DER]
 8 [ER]
 2 [LAMANDER]
 4 [MANDER]
 6 [NDER]
 9 [R]
 0 [SALAMANDER]

Unsorted data:
 0 [SALAMANDER]
 1 [ALAMANDER]
 2 [LAMANDER]
 3 [AMANDER]
 4 [MANDER]
 5 [ANDER]
 6 [NDER]
 7 [DER]
 8 [ER]
 9 [R]


String: [ABLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
Sorted data:
20 [ ELBA]
10 [ ERE I SAW ELBA]
 8 [ I ERE I SAW ELBA]
14 [ I SAW ELBA]
16 [ SAW ELBA]
 4 [ WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
24 [A]
 0 [ABLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 6 [AS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
18 [AW ELBA]
23 [BA]
 1 [BLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
13 [E I SAW ELBA]
 3 [E WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
21 [ELBA]
11 [ERE I SAW ELBA]
 9 [I ERE I SAW ELBA]
15 [I SAW ELBA]
22 [LBA]
 2 [LE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
12 [RE I SAW ELBA]
 7 [S I ERE I SAW ELBA]
17 [SAW ELBA]
19 [W ELBA]
 5 [WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]

Unsorted data:
 0 [ABLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 1 [BLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 2 [LE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 3 [E WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 4 [ WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 5 [WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 6 [AS I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 7 [S I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 8 [ I ERE I SAW ELBA]
 9 [I ERE I SAW ELBA]
10 [ ERE I SAW ELBA]
11 [ERE I SAW ELBA]
12 [RE I SAW ELBA]
13 [E I SAW ELBA]
14 [ I SAW ELBA]
15 [I SAW ELBA]
16 [ SAW ELBA]
17 [SAW ELBA]
18 [AW ELBA]
19 [W ELBA]
20 [ ELBA]
21 [ELBA]
22 [LBA]
23 [BA]
24 [A]
```

It's not easy to use the standard C [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) function for this task because you really need some auxilliary data in the sort function.  Both BSD and Linux provide a function `qsort_r()` that takes an extra parameter.  Sadly, the interfaces of the two functions are different and incompatible.

This code uses the BSD implementation of `qsort_r()` — the changes required to make it work with Linux are easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
** BSD variant of qsort_r():
**      void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, void *thunk,
**                   int (*compar)(void *, const void *, const void *));
** Linux variant of qsort_r():
**      void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
**                   int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *),
**                   void *thunk);
** The code implemented uses the BSD variant.
*/

static int str_comparator(void *thunk, const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    char **suff = thunk;
    int i1 = *(const int *)v1;
    int i2 = *(const int *)v2;
    return strcmp(suff[i1], suff[i2]);
}

static void sort_substrings(size_t length, const char seq[length], size_t index[length])
{
    const char *suff[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; seq[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        suff[i] = &seq[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }
    qsort_r(index, length, sizeof(index[0]), suff, str_comparator);
}

static void test_sort_substrings(const char *str)
{
    size_t length = strlen(str);
    size_t index[length];

    sort_substrings(length, str, index);

    int width = (length > 9) ? 2 : 1;

    printf("\nString: [%s]\n", str);
    printf("Sorted data:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%*zu [%s]\n", width, index[i], &str[index[i]]);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Unsorted data:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%*zu [%s]\n", width, i, &str[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    test_sort_substrings("HELLO");
    test_sort_substrings("SALAMANDER");
    test_sort_substrings("ABLE WAS I ERE I SAW ELBA");
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the same output as before.

Comment: Your code addressed the problem completely, the [Suffix Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) algorithm. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a 2D array of char to hold the suffixes of `HELLO`. You already have `"HELLO"` stored in a string, and each character has it's own address in memory. All you need is to declare an array of pointers (one for each char in `seq`) and initialize and sort the pointers. That will give you a sorted array of pointers referencing the `suff` of `seq` in sort order.

For example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char seq[] = "HELLO";
    size_t n = strlen (seq), i, j;
    char *suff[n];

    for (i = 0; seq[i]; i++)    /* initialize pointers */
        suff[i] = &seq[i];

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)     /* bubblesort pointers */
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1 - j; i++)
            if(strcmp(suff[i], suff[i+1]) > 0) {
                char *tmp = suff[i];
                suff[i] = suff[i+1];
                suff[i+1] = tmp;
            }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* output sorted suff */
        printf ("suff[%zu] : %s\n", i, suff[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(I still can't fix your `"LO"` sort before `"LLO"` issue....)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bshellosfx
suff[0] : ELLO
suff[1] : HELLO
suff[2] : LLO
suff[3] : LO
suff[4] : O
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. If you absolutely have to use a 2D array, it's doable, it is just less efficient.

Comment: You're a saver. Still burning candles until this. I manually mis-typed the LLO and LO order and presented the problem wrongly. You're code is perfect. Just have to store the rearranged indices into an array since it's the required output. Thank you very much. Godspeed.

Comment: Glad I could help. There are usually several ways to skin any cat, the trick is finding the easiest way. This one is just a lot easier that working with a 2D array approach.